# Postgres Select from a Table Based On Query Result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables with identical columns, in an identical order.  I have a desire to join across one of the two tables, depending on a subquery condition.  For example, assume I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
    bid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    cid INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE a1 (
    aid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    bid INT NOT NULL REFERENCES b
);

CREATE TABLE a2 (
    aid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    bid INT NOT NULL REFERENCES b
);
```

I would like a query, that performs a join across either *a1* or *a2* based on some condition.  Something like:

```
WITH z AS (
  SELECT cid, someCondition FROM someTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CASE z.someCondition THEN a1 ELSE a2 END
JOIN b USING (bid)
WHERE cid = (SELECT cid FROM z);
```

However, the above doesn't work.  Is there some way to conditionally join across *a1* or *a2*, depending on some boolean condition stored in table *z*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the conditions are exclusive (I expect they are): just do *both* queries and `UNION ALL` them, with the *smart union* construct:

```
WITH z AS (
  SELECT cid
        , (cid %3) AS some_condition -- Fake ... 
        FROM  b
  )
SELECT *
  FROM a1
  JOIN b USING (bid)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM z
        WHERE some_condition = 1 AND cid = b.cid )
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM a2
  JOIN b USING (bid)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM z
        WHERE some_condition = 2 AND cid = b.cid )
        ;
```

---

A somewhat different syntax to do the same:

```
WITH z AS (
  SELECT cid
        , (cid %3) AS some_condition 
        FROM  b
)
SELECT *
  FROM a1
  JOIN b ON a1.bid = b.bid
        AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM z
        WHERE some_condition = 1 AND cid = b.cid )
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM a2
  JOIN b ON a2.bid = b.bid
        AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM z
        WHERE some_condition = 2 AND cid = b.cid )
        ;
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  In truth, table *a1* is a superset of table *a2*, and the real question I am trying to ask is: `IF EXISTS in *a2* OR (condition AND EXISTS in *a1*)`, which seems like a great fit for your proposal. I may even move the *UNION ALL* into another subquery, so I can perform the join only once.

Comment: Performing the JOIN only once is generally a bad idea: In my example the two JOINs can make of indexes. After your UNION the indexes will not be of any use. (BTW: joins are cheap, it is not 1985 anymore) Note: there is no `IF` in SQL. You don't need it: just move the condition to the WHERE clause.

Comment: I don't think the indexes argument matters to me... in the real tables, there will either be zero or one matches from table *a1* or *a2*, and I am taking that one result and joining up a chain of 4 tables.  I don't want to duplicate the same logic multiple times.  EXAMPLE: `WITH z AS (...), y AS (SELECT bid FROM a1 WHERE aid = 7 AND some_condition UNION ALL SELECT bid FROM a2 WHERE aid = 7 AND NOT some_condition) SELECT COUNT(1)::INT::BOOLEAN FROM b WHERE bid = (SELECT * FROM y) AND cid = (SELECT cid FROM z)`

Answer (score 3):

SQL syntax does not allow conditional joins. 
Probably the simplest way to achieve a similar effect is to use a dynamic query in a plpgsql function, which may look like this:

```
create function conditional_select(acid int, some_condition boolean)
returns table (aid int, bid int, cid int)
language plpgsql as $$
declare
    tname text;
begin
    if some_condition then tname = 'a1';
    else tname = 'a2';
    end if;

    return query execute format ($fmt$
        select a.aid, b.bid, b.cid 
        from %s a
        join b using(bid)
        where cid = %s;
        $fmt$, tname, acid);
end $$;


select * from conditional_select(1, true)
```

Comment: I personally prefer @wildplasser's answer, simply because it doesn't require a custom database function.  However, this is still a great approach.

Answer (score 1):

If, like in your example, you have only a few columns that you want to output, you can use the `CASE` statement for every column:

```
SELECT CASE z.someCondition THEN a1.aid ELSE a2.aid END AS aid,
       CASE z.someCondition THEN a1.bid ELSE a2.bid END AS bid
FROM b
JOIN a1 ON a1.bid = b.bid
JOIN a2 ON a2.bid = b.bid
JOIN someTable z USING (cid);
```

Depending on the size of tables `a1` and `a2` and how many columns you have to output, this may or my not be faster than Klin's solution with a function, which is inherently slower than plain SQL and even more so because of the dynamic query. Given that `z.someCondition` is a `boolean` value already, the `CASE` evaluation will be very fast. Small tables + few columns = this solution; large tables + many columns = Klin's solution.